# C# - Common Password Prevention Implementation

Tags: c#, .net, security, passwords, nuget

Having read a fair bit about password policy and strength, I wanted to implement a common password library to **not** allow a user to select.

Rather than store the list of passwords on a server (and have to manually update them), I considered reading them from a live source such as [SecLists](https://github.com/danielmiessler/SecLists). That would probably work, but would still either have to manually update the path, if new sets were released, or have some way of avoiding pulling from the source every time a user is registered.

I wanted to see **if there was a well-used C# library of common passwords** to avoid, so an update would be as simple as updating a nuget package. Does such a thing exist, or is the use of such a library compromising your password security?

However by allowing someone knowledge of what passwords you don't allow, then those can be excluded when trying to gain access to your system. So I'm at a loss as to how best to tackle the problem. We have been told we **must** use a common password list alongside our other security options.

I've seen some nice js implementation of how to tackle this with a password policy slider, so I suspect an elegant solution is out there somewhere

Comment: By the sounds of it, you need to weigh up which is worse: users choosing passwords you would like to blacklist, or attackers being able to exclude that same blacklist from their attacks.

Comment: Just use a warning on their sign-up/change password screen that it is recommended that their password meet minimal complexity requirements and again when they ignore it.  Stick it in the T&C and have them acknowledge it.  If they proceed they acknowledge that you won't be held responsible

Comment: Actually it is a good idea to reject passwords which are listed as the most common passwords, because those are always very weak passwords. Most of them are ruled out by a minimal password length anyway. Password complexity rules on the other side are not reliable and can interfere with good password schemes. See also https://security.stackexchange.com/q/188762/8343 .

Comment: Just had a quick look around, this one [CommonPasswordsValidator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommonPasswordsValidator) seems to be well implemented.

Comment: @martinstoeckli that's almost exactly what I was looking for as a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR Don't do this

There are many compromised password lists on the internet, and effectively you could check them all with a simple check:

```
bool Match(string newPassword)
{
    var passwords = File.ReadAllLines("passwords.lst");
    return passwords.Any(x=> x == newPassword);
}
```

BUT
Users are stupid.  The harder you make it to use a password, the more likely they are to write it on a post-it note stuck to the monitor.   At the end of the day, it's their account, it it gets compromised, it's not your problem (assuming it doesn't mean they can then get access to system resources, which IS your problem).

Comment: And then adding 2fa is better than making it harder to choose a password.

Comment: On the system I'm writing at the moment, there will be NO password.  It will always be "put in your email address, we'll send you a secure link to access the site".

Comment: @Neil It's a valid point, users **are** stupid. Unfortunately, as part of getting certification from an external company, we are being asked to do this and it's a difficult one to judge

Comment: Nice.   Two-stage authentication is even better

Comment: Current NIST standards actually recommend doing this: [NIST](https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/sp800-63b.html)